# if condition with href in php

Tags: php, html

i have a menu as code mentions below...

```
<ul class="left_menu">
     <li class="odd"><a href=\"?x=nk\">NOKIA</a></li>
     <li class="even"><a href="services.html">SONY ERISSON</a></li>
     <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">LG</a></li>
     <li class="even"><a href="services.html">ALCATEL</a></li>
     <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">BIRD</a></li>
     <li class="even"><a href="services.html">SAMSUNG</a></li>
     <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">DO MOBILE</a></li>
     <li class="even"><a href="services.html">iPHONE</a></li>
     <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">ETEL</a></li>
     <li class="even"><a href="services.html">HTC</a></li>
     <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">BLACKBERRY</a></li>
     <li class="even"><a href="services.html">I-MATE</a></li>
     <li class="odd"><a href="services.html">VODAFONE</a></li>
    </ul>


 <?php
 $page = $_GET['x'];
  switch ($page)
  {
  case "nk":
  include("nokia.php");
   break;

 case "SONY ERISSON":
  include("sony_erisson.php");
   break;

case "LG":
 include("lg.php");
  break;

 case "ALCATEL":
   inlcude("alcatel.php");
    break;

case "BIRD":
 include("bird.php");
   break;

case "SAMSUNG":
  include("samsung.php");
   break;

case "DO MOBILE":
  include("do_mobile.php");
   break;

case "iPHONE":
   include ("iphone.php");
    break;

case "ETEL":
   include ("etel.php");
   break;

case "HTC":
  include ("htc.php");
    break;

case "BLACKBERRY":
   include ("blackberry.php");
    break;

case "I-MATE":
 include ("imate.php");
  break;

case "VODAFONE":
 include ("vodafone.php");
  break;


default:
  include("default.php");
}
 ?>
```

now what i need to do is.. i need to include the contents of each pages once the user click on the particular phone category. simply i need to do.. now lets say.. if nokia is clicked.. then i need to include the nokia.php contents to this page which is index.php.. how can i do tihs?? i have written some codes above.. but it does not work.. any one could help me pleasee..

Comment: If I get you right, all you need to do is add the needed GET value to your link. E.g.: services.html?x=catname

Answer (score 1):

what are those backslashes doing in your code ? ;)

`<a href=\"?x=nk\">`

if you remove them, probably it'll work

Comment: well i tried.. it pumped this error msg: Undefined index: x in C:\wamp\www\mobile\index.php on line 156. and this is the code at line 156: `$page = $_GET['x'];`

Comment: add `if ( isset( $_GET['x'] ) ) { rest of your code }` you see this error because $_GET is empty before you click on NOKIA

Comment: i tried your code. this is how i did.. `if ( isset( $_GET['x'] ) ) { my code } else { echo 'GET is not set'; }` therefore, i was able to see "GET is not set" which means my $_GET['x'] does not hold a value. how can i get the value of `<a href="#"> NOKIA </a>` once the user is clicked i need to read the content of nokia.php into my index.php this is why i need to get the value of `<a href="#"> NOKIA </a>`

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to escape quotes in HTML:

```
 <li class="odd"><a href="?x=nk">NOKIA</a></li>
```

but if you reffering from an html files you can't run php code in it. you must have php extension for your files to be able to run it.

Comment: well i tried.. it pumped this error msg: Undefined index: x in C:\wamp\www\mobile\index.php on line 156. and this is the code at line 156:   $page = $_GET['x'];

Comment: how does your url look when you recieve your error? the correct url must be ".../?x=nk"

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your code like this:

```
$x = $_GET['x']; // the name of the file
if ( isset( $x ) ) { 
    $filename = "/path/to/".$x.".php";
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        include($filename);
    }
    else {
        include("default.php");
    }
 }
```

Comment: not very good, isset checked too late (ERROR) and it's easy to hack with that kind of code ( you don't check what is in $x )

Comment: because this is only an example ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with Vasil.

Well I think the whole thing needs a redesign (just my opinion), building a web site without a single entry point reminds me of many many ears ago.. and in the run you will face the drawbacks in many aspects.

If you cannot commit to an MVC at least go with the old style single entry point this way you only need to load things once in one place.

This means that you never call a file directly like this:

```
<a href=somescript.php>Click me</a>
```

insted you do

`<a href=index.php?scr=somescript>Click me</a>` as mentioned right above.

---

However in case you don't know things have moved forward...

-You can load results of php scripts (like db queries or whatever) without even refreshing the page, I use it a lot in html forms [http xml connect with GET or POST - I use POST my self]

-You can even load css files or scripts or change page contents without refreshing the page again.

-Can use mvc to have things esaily done and controlled

-Can create css on the fly with php

-Can output anything anywhere anytime in your code even cancel previous string to ouput or cancel previous css or js loaded before without concerning a bit how and where all this will be shown-loaded. Think of this like a big tube-pipe that any script adds or remove stuff and at the end all this is echoed. MVC- Pattern are some keywords related to it.

Whenever time allows to implement a new technology I think it is worth.

Comment: Please need more explanation. highly appreciating all your comments.